# Custom Classloader Need and Limitations of Default classloaders

Tags: java

What is need for an application or system to go for Custom class loader?

What are the limitations of the current set of classloaders that generally web application use ( Server + JVM )

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We have used custom classloaders in our application to build a plugin framework. This classloader allowed us to embed jar files inside the plugin file (Which is also a jar file).

Comment: But what was the limitation with the classloaders that was at the system disposal

Comment: Updated my answer to reply to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrate one of the usage of Custom class loader, I will take an example of my implementation,

Couple of months ago I have built a custom class loader to load a class created at run time from xml data source.  The requirement was to create a java source files from a XML files, compile, jar it.

In order to load/execute these classes which resides in a DB I had to write custom class loader (extending `URLClassLoader`) since all the operation happening at run time, default/system classloader is not aware of the new classes(jar) , or not in the claspath.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `ClassLoader` to
1. Create new classes (for example, when custom proxying needed)
2. Redefine existing classes, when on some reason `java.lang.instrumentation` (javaagent) is not available.